# When the program runs, writes ->->->->. Why does it do that?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Here is the textfile that the program must read, and put every num. in a different variable.
The first num., in this case 3, is the n, and tells the procedure the program how many times to be done. Between the nums., there is a space.

The text file f is like that

```
3 2
2 1
1 5
4 2
```

When it runs the code the following thing keeps being writen

```
->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->
->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->
->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->
->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->
->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->
->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->->
```

Why do that happeen?

Can anyone please help me with this program?

The code is the following one.

```
Program thefinalp;

Uses SysUtils;

Var
  f: Text;
  m, d: Integer;
  n: Char;
  c: String[1];

  a, e: array of Integer;
  LowArr: Integer;
  HighArr: Integer;
  ArrayLen: Integer;
  i: Integer;

begin
  Assign(f, 'd:\tempfiles\finalp.txt');
  Reset(f);

  repeat
    Readln(f, n);
    Write(n);
  until (n = ' ');

  Read(f, c);
  Write(c);

  while not SeekEoln(f) do
  begin
    read(f, d);
    Write(d);
  End;
  Readln;
  Writeln;

  StrToIntDef(n, m);

  setlength(a, m);
  LowArr := Low(a);
  HighArr := High(a);
  ArrayLen := Length(a);

  setlength(e, m);
  LowArr := Low(e);
  HighArr := High(e);
  ArrayLen := Length(e);

  for i := LowArr to HighArr do

  begin

    repeat
      Read(f, a[i]);
      Write(a[i]);
    until (n = ' ');

    Read(f, c);
    Write(c);

    while not SeekEoln(f) do
    begin
      read(f, e[i]);
      Write(e[i]);
    End;
    Readln;
    Writeln;

  End;
  Readln;

End.
```

Comment: You should indent blocks properly. Makes your code much easier to read.

Comment: Turn on compiler hints and warnings. Pay atention to what they tell you. Then use the debugger to step through the code to figure out what's going wrong. Once you've done that much, if you can't solve the problem you'll at least be able to describe it better and narrow it down.

Comment: I've fixed your code formatting (again). It's time you learned to properly format your code (both here and on your own machine) so that we don't have to keep doing it for you. It gets pretty annoying when people make no effort themselves and expect others to clean up after them. Formatting code here isn't difficult, so if you do it properly in your own code it's a matter of copy, paste and a keystroke or toolbar button click to post here properly.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the problem, i'm still a beginner, i tried to indent the code, but it seems that it needed better indent, so i searched it on the internet, so the nexy yime i'll post mycode it will be better formated. About the hints of the compiler, there was no compile message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first `repeat until`, you are `readln`ing into a **char**. The first character will appear in `n` and the remainder of the characters will be skipped entirely until the newline has been read. AT that point, your file-pointer will be at `2` on the second line of data.

Since your test is for `n=' '` then the readln will again be executed, this time delivering `2` into `n` and pushing the file-pointer to the `1` on the third line.

When eventually end-of-file is reached, a Control-Z character is 'read' from the file. This is the character you are seeing. Since it isn't <kbd>Space</kbd>, the loop continues forever.

Change the `readln` here to a `read` and **one** character will be read. (then it works, and you can go on to the next problem...)

Remember, `readln` reads until it has read a newline. `Read` reads into the variable - if it's a char, it reads one char. If it's a string, it reads a string - but not the newline.

---

```
Program thefinalp;

Uses SysUtils;

Var
f:Text;
m,d:Integer;
n:string;
n2:string;
c:String[1];

a,e:array of integer;//dynamic array//
LowArr:Integer;
HighArr:Integer;
ArrayLen:Integer;
i:Integer;
  ch : char;

function readinteger : string;
var
  st : string;
begin
  st := '';
//  read up to first digit
  repeat
    read(f,ch);
    write(ch);
  until ch in ['0'..'9'];
//accumulate digits
  repeat
    st := st + ch;
    read(f,ch);
    write(ch);
  until not (ch in ['0'..'9']);
  readinteger := st;
end;


begin
  Assign(f,'q21366050.txt');
  Reset(f);
// read first integer
  n:= readinteger;
// read second integer
  n2:= readinteger;

  m := StrToInt(n); //puts a string into an integer//

  setlength(a,m);
  LowArr:=Low(a);
  HighArr:=High(a);
  ArrayLen:=Length(a);

  setlength(e,m);
  LowArr:=Low(e);
  HighArr:=High(e);
  ArrayLen:=Length(e);

  for i:= LowArr to HighArr do
  begin
// read first integer
    n:= readinteger;
// read second integer
    n2:= readinteger;
    a[i]:=StrToInt(n); //puts a string into an integer//
    e[i]:=StrToInt(n2); //puts a string into an integer//
  End;
  Writeln;
  writeln('Results');
  for i:= LowArr to HighArr do
    writeln(inttostr(i),'=',inttostr(a[i]),',',inttostr(e[i]));
// pause to read results
  Readln;
End.
```

Unfortunately, it's a little difficult to figure out just exactly what you want to do. This routine will read the first line and then put the remaining lines into a[?] and e[?].

Using descriptive variablenames would perform some of the documentation so you can follow what is happening. Since I don't actually know, I'm having to make assumptions and make a few things up to fill in the gaps.

Looking at the main routine, first you assign a filename (I used `q21366050.txt` for my convenience) and open the file with a `reset`.

Next job is to read the first number in from the file. Now you have only shown single-digit numbers, but it's easy to set the routine to cope with a sequence.

```
n:=readinteger;
```

assigns the result of the function `readinteger` to the **string** `n`

`readinteger` works this way: first clear the string `st` which is a "local variable" - only available to this routine. Then keep reading characters into `ch` until the character read is in the range '0'..'9' - so it skips until it reads a digit. Then it adds the digit read to the string `st` and continues to read characters and accumulate them until the character found is **not** a digit. (That character, should we need it, is in `ch`) We then assign the accumulated string of digits to the resut of the function.

Hence, `n` will get the first `string` of digits in the file; the next character has been read,and we know it isn't a digit (otherwise it would have been appended to the string returned).

We then repeat the process with `n2`. All of the remaining characters before then next digit are skipped, the digit sequence returned and the following character placed in `ch`

Then we assign the resullt of converting the string `n` to an integer to `m`. You haven't described what the other number may be used for, so it's there - but unused.

Set up the two arays, `a` and `e`.

Then use the same routine to read the next integer. It doesn't matter that there are <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd> characters - we skip to the next numeric and return it. and repeat that for the second number in the line.

Convert the two numbers and put them into their respective arrays.

Do this `m` times.

inally, write a new line to the display, then another reporting `Results` and then repeat `m` times write a line containing the iteration number `i` and the values of the two arrays, `a` and `e`, all as integers-converted-to-strings and with `=` and `,` characters to show that we're not just repeating the dat read from the input.

Finally,  wait for an input from the keyboard (since the `readln` has no explicit filevar) which holds the program open until we can see the results.

Now - nominally, of course, you should also close the file before terminating...

Comment: Caould you possibly recommend me a way to move to the nexy line? Because when the program is executed, it writes only the first line, and the problem is that i need SeekEoln, because the last num. of the line must be put in a variable alone. Thank you.